# Warn to user with message in session timeout in spring boot app 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I want to display message to user as "Singed out because of inactive" in login page .

I tried the below code in spring security but its not effected .

`sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?expired")` in httpsecurity.

After session timeout , simple its redirect to the `/login` only , did't get the expired value .

Using the below versions:

Spring boot 2.0

Spring security 5.0

Comment: Did you add a session listener?

Comment: No , directly i added in http security , sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?expired")

Comment: That not enough. You have also to add a session listener.

Comment: Hey man, have you solved your problem? if yes, post your solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a snippet of my entire configuration, but this will check if the session has expired ONLY for authenticated users. When you use `.maximumSessions(1)` you are dealing with concurrent user management. That's not what you need.

In the following snippet, I check all incoming requests if they are authenticated `.anyRequest().authenticated()`. If the request is from an authenticated user (I don't check for roles) AND the session has timed out `.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl()`, redirect them back to the index page which has the login form.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/?sessionexpired=true");
  }

}
```